# Add product name in product view within a new phtml?

Tags: magento2, product, layout, template

I copied `catalog_product_view.xml` and pasted it into `app\design\frontend\Mytheme\DreamShop\Magento_Catalog\layout` folder and code is added before the `default.phtml`

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.productname" as="productname" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/productname.phtml"/>
```

[image]

Comment: You are saying that you want name of the product but code says you are showing category name. What do you want please explain more?

Comment: I want  product name

Comment: How did you add the file.phtml in your catalog page? Can you post the xml code in your question?

Comment: <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.productname" as="productname" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/productname.phtml"/>

Comment: Are you calling it in product details page?

Comment: yes! actually   i dont know exact process of add phtml pages . please  guide me with details

Comment: Where do you want to show the product name? Can you share any screenshot? And also the whole xml code not only the block code.

Answer (score 2):

Change the xml to below code:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.productname" as="productname" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/productname.phtml"/>
```

In your template file **productname.phtml** add the below code:

```
<? php echo $this->getProduct()->getName(); ?>
```

**Note:** *This should work if you are using this product in your product details page.*

Answer (score 0):

1. > app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
           <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.name" template="Magento_Catalog::productData.phtml" before="-" />
       </referenceContainer>
   </page>
   ```
2. > app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/productData.phtml

   ```
   <?php echo __('Product name : ').$this->getProduct()->getName(); ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your catalog_product_view.xml it may helps you.

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
```